# Integral of vector field over surface

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Can someone help with any hints or a proof to this question?

> **Question.** Let $\mathbf{F}$ be a $C^1$ vector field on $\mathbb{R^3}$. Show that if $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}(x_0, y_0, z_0)>0$, then there is a sphere $S$ centered at $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ such that $$\iint_{S}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{S}>0.$$

My attempt:
Let $p=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}(p)>0$ 
<s><s>$\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\text{so }p\text{ is not a critical point, and }\mathbf{F}\text{ has neither}}$</s>
<s>$\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\text{min nor max at }p.}$</s></s>
$\color{red}{(\text{and }\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}\text{ is continuous})}$, then there is a open ball $B_r(p)$(required sphere) centered at $p$ with small radius $r$ such that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}(B_r(p))>0$. Then apply the divergence theorem, we have $\iiint_{E} \text{div}\ \mathbf{F}\ dV=\iint_{S}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{S}>0$ because the volume of the ball and $\text{div }\mathbf{F}$ are both positive.

Comment: What do you mean “$\mathbf{F}$ has neither min or max at $p$“? The outputs of $\mathbf{F}$ are elements of $\mathbb{R}^3$, which does not have a standard order. In other words, in which sense can a *vector* field have a minimum or a maximum?

Comment: @Samuel M. A. Luque Oh, you are right. It is a silly mistake. It should be because of continuity. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed an open ball $\mathrm{B}_r(p)$ such that $\nabla\cdot \mathbf{F}(x)>0$ for all $x\in\ \mathrm{B}_r(p)$. However, this is true simply because the function $\nabla\cdot \mathbf{F}=\partial_x\mathbf F +\partial_y\mathbf F+\partial_z\mathbf F$ is continuous (recall that $\mathbf F$ is assumed to be $C^1$):

For $\varepsilon=\left(\nabla\cdot \mathbf{F}(p)\right)/2>0$, there exists some $r>0$ such that for all $x\in\mathrm{B}_r(p)$, $\left\lvert\nabla\cdot \mathbf{F}(x)-\nabla\cdot \mathbf{F}(p)\right\rvert<\varepsilon$, so, in particular, $\nabla\cdot \mathbf{F}(x)>0$.

The rest of your argument works.